# Is there a way to erase docker history?

Tags: docker

When building an image I have to pass in credentials to get through a corporate proxy through a build-arg. These credentials are then visible through the docker history command. Is it possible to erase or redact my credentials from the build history?

Answer (score 2):

Using a multi-stage build, you can copy the build artifacts from the first stage into a new second stage. The second stage won't have the history of the first stage.

Answer (score 0):

First use the `docker export` command to prevent sensitive data from being shown with the history command. You need to start a container from an image first. Then we can export and import the container in one line:

```
docker export <CONTAINER ID> | docker import - some-image-name:latest
```

Then you can use some common Linux tricks to shrink Docker images. One simple trick is to clear the cache of the package manager:

```
# clean apt cache
apt-get clean
```

For details, [this blog post](https://tuhrig.de/flatten-a-docker-container-or-image/) seems to support the idea.